# How to encpsulate components (toolbars) content to prevent the component (toolbar) becomes a monolith?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, architecture

I am in trouble with my toolbar code of my current app.

My toolbar covers the whole app. That means the toolbar is displayed on every page. Because of this, the toolbar is only a part of my root template (`app.component.html`) and every other page (component) is lazy-loaded by the `router-outlet`. The benefit is to avoid a whole DOM update of my toolbar.

`app.component.html`:

```html
<my-toolbar></my-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- loads specific pages lazy -->
```

But now there is a big problem. The view content (icons, texts, margins, order, etc.) of `my-toolbar.component.html` is a little bit different on every page. The displayed data is handled by a service. So my toolbar component became a very big monolith-like construct. In relation to the route, there is a big switch case like procedure to find out which content is displayed in the toolbar ... :-(

My aim is to keep the general view content in `my-toolbar.component.html` and the specific view content should be "injected" with `<ng-content>` by the specific page. But I can use `<ng-content>` only if I put the `<my-toolbar></my-toolbar>` directly in an page template like:

```html
<my-toolbar>
  <!-- specific content -->
</my-toolbar>
```

At the level of a lower-level page component, I am not able to access the higher-level toolbar component. Is there still a way to "inject" the specific content from a page component to the higher toolbar component? Note: I want to avoid CSS hacks like negative margin, positioning, etc.

I hope my bad English was understood. ó.Ò

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read here I suppose the best way would be to leverage the nested routed outlets.

Eg app page would be changed to contain root router outlet

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And pages would contain nested router outlets.

Eg, one page would be like

```html
<my-toolbar>
    <custom-page-one-content></custom-page-one-content>
</my-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Another page would be like

```html
<my-toolbar>
    <custom-page-two-content></custom-page-two-content>
</my-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

It would lead to nice modularization and probably to improved lazy loading.